# completely remove edb-debugger from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: uninstallation, ubuntu-18.04, edb

I was trying to upgrade my edb debugger from 0.9 to 1.0.  I cloned the repo from github, compiled it and installed it.  Unfortunately I forgot to uninstall the old version itself so I ran into some problems.  Ithen decided to remove all of edb and start from scratch.  I did all sorts of sudo commands (i.e. purge autoremove etc) yet the edb icon is still in my applications menu and works (to a degree cause then I get failed to load necessary plugin).  Probably help to mention that I used cmake to compile and install the newer version.

So the question is how do I go about removing all of edb and start over ?

idzireit

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the edb-debugger package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove edb-debugger
```

If you also want to delete your local/config files for edb-debugger then this will work.

```
sudo apt-get purge edb-debugger

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove edb-debugger
```

To fully install edb-debugger ,follow this link
https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/wiki/Installing

Or else try this in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install edb-debugger
```

If this process do not work, please comment below

Comment: going over the processes again I am still unable to fully remove edb.  it is still in my app menu and running until it can not find the symbols

Answer (score 0):

I have made a very ugly work around o get it working without any errors.  When it loads up I changed the symbol directory to point at the symbol directory from the build.  In my case this would be the following:
/home/USERNAME/edb-debugger/build/plugins/SymbolViewer/CMakeFiles/SymbolViewer_autogen.dir

Then I did the same with the plugin directroy and made it point to:
/home/USERNAME/edb-debugger/build

I left the third directory (Session Directory) alone.  Might play around with that at a later date but it is working even though loaded with ugly hacks.

If anyone has any better answers please advise how to prettify this fix up some.